# Custom build script to avoid libraries name collisions?

Tags: android, android-library, name-conflict

When using Android libraries if more than one project (main or libraries) defines the same resource, the higher-priority project's copy gets used and replaces the previous one.

This is a problem when writing a reusable library because it forces you to prefix every resource name to avoid conflicts. See the [Android Parcel Project](http://andparcel.com/) for more information on the topic.

Now what I'd like to do is a script that would, prior to compilation, prefix the name of every resource from all libraries with their package name. For this I intend to use the generated ant build script and add a custom step to it.

Do you know if that would be possible? Do you see a better solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know if that would be possible?

If you have source code to the library, I suppose you could do this. Any place you refer to resource IDs dynamically (reflection, `getIdentifier()`, etc.) would have to be adjusted manually, I suspect. And you may not be able to get assistance from the library author given that you modified their code.

I'd also work on trying to convince the library author to add resource prefixes in future editions of their library.

Comment: I'm making an extensible app using pluggable "modules" (each one being an Android libraries). So in my case I can ask module writers to not use reflections or such. Then I'll make something similar to your ParcelHelper, but that would automatically add the package names when looking up the IDs. This way module developers could completely ignore collisions issues.

Comment: Your module developers have no choice but to handle the prefixes themselves, unless you are also going to force them to use your Ant script. After all, they need to test their module.

Comment: Well yes, but they'll need the SDK etc in any case so making the Ant script mandatory is not really a problem. I think it's way more convenient like this rather than having to use prefixes.

Comment: Actually wouldn't it be interesting as a general purpose solution for developers of closed source libraries? Write your code without thinking of collisions, access resources using helper methods, and export a jar with names made unique at compile-time. They'd only need the custom Ant script for release.

Comment: "but they'll need the SDK etc in any case so making the Ant script mandatory is not really a problem" -- tell that to Eclipse users. :-) "Actually wouldn't it be interesting as a general purpose solution for developers of closed source libraries?" -- if you can pull it off, it certainly seems useful.